# Sound not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, 14.04

[image]

Initially it was working fine and suddenly it stopped working. After installing AMAROK audio player. 
This is about the ALSAMIXER

[image]

Looking for help ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. **Reinstall alsa-utils**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install alsa-utils --reinstall
   ```
2. **Download and install alsa-lib**

   On this page you will find all versions https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-lib

   Or find [Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/alsa-lib_1.0.25.orig.tar.bz2) a link to version 1.0.25-4(the stable version)

   - Extract the archive and run the following code in the extracted directory

     ```
     ./configure && make
     ```
   - Then

     ```
     sudo make install
     ```

Comment: after doing the above (thank-you for this solution!) - reload alsa via the command: sudo alsa force-reload and when you check your sound settings, you should see all of your devices.

Comment: I have the same problem except: Card : HDA ATI SB, Chipset : Realtek ALC887-VD. Sound works except in vlc, no sound control on top right of the screen. I tried your method, it doesn't help. Any idea ?

Comment: try resetting your vlc

Comment: hi , couldn't resolve issue with steps you mentioned. Cant figure out where the issue lies @Jax-L . I observe issue system wide , not only in VLC

Comment: I have followed your hints but it doesn't show the devices in the "Play sounds through" list. What have I to do?

thanks in advance

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3, and several programs have problems with my ALSA drivers. Everything sounds "scratchy" after the audio plays for a while, or programs hang or crash due to ALSA-related errors. So, I followed the steps above today. Hoping it works.

Comment: I am actually using 1.0.27.2; will the downgrade affect my ALSA drivers' performance?