# Sound not working in laptop speakers. Headphones fine

Tags: 14.04, sound, windows-8, alsa, headphones

I am using ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS on Dell Inspiron. I have hda-intel soundcard. For quite a few days now, my laptop sound is not coming from the speakers, and only from headphones. I have tried selecting the in-built speakers in pavucontrol both when the headphones were plugged in and were not. When headphones were plugged in, and I selected in-built speakers, the sound still came from the headphones. When not plugged in, there was no sound at all.

I have tried reinstalling alsamixer, killing pulseaudio, changing volumes in alsamixer. Nothing has worked so far. Here are some screenshots of alsamixer.

Just after running alsamixer:
[image: Just after running alsamixer]
Not sure if the above is normal, since I have to change the soundcard first to get the next state:
[image: Selected another sound card]
Again I am not sure if there should be columns about headphones, since they are not plugged in. After plugging in the headphones, it changes to:
[image: After plugging in headphones]
Which is not much of a change. Just the speakers got muted. On disconnecting the speakers, they go back to 100.

Please help. I have already seen other threads like this, but didn't get any answer that worked. Thank you in advance

EDIT: I have dual boot with Windows 8. So I know that it is not a hardware problem

EDIT 2: Noticed something new. In alsamixer, Whenever I mute the headphones(2nd column) while unplugged, even the speaker and master columns are muted automatically. I don't think this is a normal behavior. One more thing I should probably add: Everytime I plug in the headphones, a new pop-up asks me if I have plugged in a headphone, headset or Microphone. This didn't happen with my previous headphone.

EDIT 3: I have dual boot with Windows 8.1, but I didn't know that this was relevant to the problem.

Comment: try this :
              http://askubuntu.com/questions/457619/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: If you still have your installation CD/DVD/USB-pendrive/etc. you could boot into a live session and try if the laptop speakers work - it could theoretically be a hardware problem. (although it is very unlikely)

Comment: @Kai I have a dual boot with Windows 8. The speakers work perfectly fine. But you are right, I should add this in the question

Comment: @P_O_I_S_O_N All my audio devices are displayed in the sound settings. But all the audio is still directed towards headphones regardless of my selection. Nevertheless, I tried the solution, and it didn't work.

Comment: "Restart does not work." Yea I find the same issue that restart wont work, I must completely turn off the machine every time I switch between the two. Have you overcome this or is it the only way??

Comment: No luck trying to overcome this. It is as if even turning off fast boot in windows 8 doesn't stop it from executing a "fast reboot" in a sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some research, I found out that the problem was with me having dual boot with windows 8.1. Found the answer on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464388/no-sound-from-laptop-speakers-in-ubuntu-14-04-after-booting-into-windows-8-1). As it turned out, I already had [disabled Fast boot in Windows 8.1](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown-fast-boot-feature-works/). In addition to that, I discovered I had to fully turn off from Windows and then turn on the laptop again. **Restart** does **not** work.

Marking this as the answer.