# Sound not working in Ubuntu 14.04LTS after upgrading from 13.10

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04LTS from 13.10. Before upgrade sound was working fine, but after that its not working. I tried solving this issue from a reference link

[Sound not working in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457619/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)

but still my problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Could you apply this procedure let us know if you see any error message.
[Pulseaudio Log](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log)

Don't paste your log file in this site but use this one [Paste Bin](http://pastebin.com/) and share the link.

Sometimes uninstall pulseaudio and resintall it solve the problem

```
sudo apt-get remove –purge pulseaudio gstreamer* esound*
```

I put Esound package for be sure unisntalled because it's obsolete and occur bug (never mind). Following a reboot apply:

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
```

Add you login in the audio group:

```
 sudo adduser $USER audio
```

then reboot

May help.

Comment: Hi,I have tried your procedure but not getting any error, but still last command not terminating....any thing is going wrong..

Comment: Hi, sorry i forget to terminate that command. I got the logs from pulseverbose.log and have posted into Paste Bin link which you have given.

Comment: Better if you share the link, and I put an upgrade in my answer may help.

Comment: Hi, Tried your given answer but its also not solving problem, but after doing this sound icon it self disappear which was showing near battery icon. And after playing videos its showing "An error occurred Could not initialize supporting library" error message.

Comment: Did you you reinstall pulseaudio? check with `sudo dpkg -l |grep pulseaudio |grep ^i`

Comment: Hi, I have reinstall pulseaudio.

Comment: After running that command its showing gstreamer plugin for pulseaudio, pulseaudio sound server, bluetooth module for pulseaudio sound server....

Comment: Hi, Please find below the link where pulseaudio logs are there.....http://pastebin.com/u/deepak8625

Comment: type alsamixer in a terminal then type on "F6" and choice "HDA intel PCH" as card sound. Then check all volume are up. Follow this may help : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/AlsaInfo

Comment: Hi,I have already selected HDA intel PCH" as card sound and also uploaded information in the alsa-project server below link.... http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=a2e186b28c607b7191ac40bf4b37ae90a7de2209

Comment: I put a add in my first anwser be sure that you loggin is in the audio Check that. I can not help anymore as I've got some problem with my sound card too. :-/

Comment: Hi, Its not adding user can please tell me how to add. My user is deepak so i run .. sudo adduser -G audio $deepak  command, but its not working its asking Option g is ambiguous (gecos, gid, group).

Comment: this one is better : `sudo adduser $USER audio `    Did you have your sound card activated in your BIOS

Comment: Hi, I have checked from BOIS not getting any option for sound card. can you please tell me any other option how to check this.

Comment: Hi, I have checked from BOIS not getting any option for sound card. can you please tell me any other option how to check this. First time boot sound option is not showing, but when unckecking and again checking point from All Setting->Sound->Show sound volume in the menu bar them only sound icon is showing near battery symbol. But always its showing muted and not able to change to unmute. If playing any videos its showing  "An error occurred Could not initialize supporting library" error message is coming.

Comment: Hi, I have solved my problem for headset but still speakers are not working. I have taken the reference form the links.....http://askubuntu.com/questions/483397/missing-sound-volume-icon-on-screen-top-14-04   and https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/UpgradingAlsa/DKMS   .But after boot sound icon not visible but if run command "pulseaudio --start" then sound icon is visible.