# "Could not initialize supporting library" while playing videos through default player in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, alsa

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04LTS from 13.10. Before upgrade sound was working fine, but after that its not working.Before trying below reference sound was working only through headphone but after below these  reference sound not working neither through headphone nor speakers(in-build).
I tried solving from below reference link.

[Sound not working in Ubuntu 14.04LTS after upgrading from 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544618/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04lts-after-upgrading-from-13-10)

And i have attached logs for pulseaudio to the below reference link.

http://pastebin.com/vys0c3rn

but after this sound icon always showing mute which was showing near battery icon, but when checked from system settings->sound->output volume its showing unmuted. I tried changing from mute to unmute from icon near battery icon but its not changing. And after playing videos its showing "An error occurred Could not initialize supporting library" error message is coming. Please suggest how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is the "show sound volume in the menu bar" box checked in All Settings>Sound?

Comment: Hi, Sound icon is there in all setting.

Comment: when i clicked on sound icon its showing unmuted and if clicked output icon its showing blank below "play sound through' icon.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem for headset but still speakers are not working. I have taken the reference from the mentioned link.....[Sound not working in Ubuntu 14.04LTS after upgrading from 13.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544618/sound-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04lts-after-upgrading-from-13-10)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, typing in the command `sudo apt-get install pulseaudio` helps me watch different videos on Videos. Just remember to not remove PulseAudio, or you might get this message that I got in Videos:

> Could not initialize supporting library.

It's because I don't have PulseAudio installed. Thank you!